# Mac Catalyst - standard dialog for save file

Tags: dialog, save-as, mac-catalyst

I want to implement standard Save As dialog in mac catalyst app. It should behave as in TextEdit - open a dialog, let user choose location and file format, and create file after clicking Save.

I have found UIDocumentPickerViewController , but I don't know:

1. How to let user choose file format from the list of formats I offer
2. How to initialize UIDocumentPickerViewController for export without already existing file. (I want to create file only after I know file format and location). I know about this contructor: init(urls: [URL], in: UIDocumentPickerMode) , which seems promising, but is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re on the right lines with `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, but you must provide a URL and use `UIDocumentPickerViewController(forExporting urls: [URL])`.

To get the URL, write the file data to the temporary directory, then pass the temporary URL as the argument.

Comment: this answer is correct. Should be the accepted answer. Write the data to a temp URL, then export.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you import AppKit (which is allowed on the Mac side of a Mac Catalyst app,) the error message is clear:

[image: nssavepanel catalyst error]

Comment: It doesn't seem like an answer at all

Comment: That's because there is no answer.